# Receber erro em requisição cUrl

Tags: php

Estou tentando receber o erro em um retorno de cUrl

```
 ini_set("display_errors",true);
 ini_set("display_startup_erros",1);
 error_reporting(E_ALL && E_NOTICE);
 error_reporting( E_ALL | E_STRICT ); // PHP 5.3
 error_reporting( E_ALL ); // Todas as outras versões 

  class consultaCep {

    private $phpUtil;
    private $erro = "";

    public function __construct($_phpUtil) {
         $this->phpUtil = $_phpUtil;
    }

    function consultarCepViaCep ($_cep)    {

        $_cep = $this->phpUtil->limpaCaracters($_cep);

        $urliaCep = sprintf('http://viacep.com.br/ws/%s/json/ ', $_cep);

          $ch = curl_init();
          curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $urliaCep);
          curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
          curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
          curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
          curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

          $data = curl_exec($ch);

          $data = json_decode($data);

          if(isset($data->erro)) {

              $this->erro = $data->erro;

          } else {

              return $data;

          }

    }

    public function getErro () {
        return $this->erro;
    }

}
```

Quando faço:

```
require_once "_controlls/_util/PhpUtil.php";
$phpUtil = new PhpUtil();

$_POST["cep"] = "11111111";
$consultaCep = new consultaCep($phpUtil);
$consultarCep = $consultaCep->consultarCepViaCep($_POST["cep"]);      

if($consultaCep->getErro() != "") {

  print "Erro: ".$consultaCep->getErro();

} else {

  print "<pre>";
  print_r($consultarCep);
  print "</pre>";  
}
```

Quando está correto, o retorno vem normal.

Mas quando há erro de cep inválido dá erro tipo 1

Ma quando o erro é de cep incompleto não dá erro e nem completa os dados

Comment: `curl_init` é um tipo de exceção? o `catch` deve capturar uma especifica do contario passa reto no bloco.

Comment: no caso qual a saida? curl_exec? Já terntei, não deu!

Answer (score 0):

O problema é que `curl_init` não é um tipo de exceção. `CURL` não tem manipulação de exceção. A tua abordagem terá de ser diferente. Terás que estender a class Exceptions o fazer algo similar a [isto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11297320/using-a-try-catch-with-curl-in-php).

Comment: alterei a pergunta

Answer (score -1):

Bom, resolvi assim. Mas acho que deve haver uma forma mais correta de verificar isso. Se existir, por favor, me ajudem. Pois usando o webservice dos Correios esta demorando até 30 segundos para cair o retorno.

Erros

```
 ini_set("display_errors",true);
 ini_set("display_startup_erros",1);
 error_reporting(E_ALL && E_NOTICE);
 error_reporting( E_ALL | E_STRICT ); // PHP 5.3
 error_reporting( E_ALL ); // Todas as outras versões
```

Classe

```
  class consultaCep {

    private $phpUtil;
    private $erro = "";

    public function __construct($_phpUtil) {
         $this->phpUtil = $_phpUtil;
    }

    function consultarCepViaCep ($_cep)    {

        $_cep = $this->phpUtil->limpaCaracters($_cep);

        $urliaCep = sprintf('http://viacep.com.br/ws/%s/json/', $_cep);

          $ch = curl_init();
          curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $urliaCep);
          curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
          curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
          curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
          curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
          $data = curl_exec($ch);         

          if($data==false) {

              $this->erro = "Erro de interoperação! Verifique o CEP digitado";

          } else {

              $data = json_decode($data);

              if (isset($data->erro)) {

                   switch ($data->erro==1)  {
                       case  1 : $erro = "CEP não encontrado";
                       break;
                       case  1 : $erro = "Sistema Falhou";
                       break;
                  }

                  $this->erro = $erro;

              } else {

              return $data;

              }           

          }

    }

    public function getErro () {
        return $this->erro;
    }

}
```

Faço:
    require_once "_controlls/_util/PhpUtil.php"; // só para retirar os pontos e traços
    $phpUtil = new PhpUtil();

```
$_POST["cep"] = "11111111";
$consultaCep = new consultaCep($phpUtil);
$consultarCep = $consultaCep->consultarCepViaCep($_POST["cep"]);      

if($consultaCep->getErro() != "") {

  print $consultaCep->getErro();

} else {

  print "<pre>";
  print_r($consultarCep);
  print "</pre>";  
}
```